# Unreachable code in if statement inside a while loop

Tags: python-3.x

I was trying to make a menu with a while loop to keep repeating until a valid input was entered. This is the code that I have:

```
print("1) Play game")
print("")
print("2) Instructions")
print("")
print("3) Quit")
print("")

while True:
    try:
        menu = int(input("Make a selection: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Sorry, your input was not valid")
    continue
    
    if menu > 3 or menu < 1:
        print("Please use a number in the range 1-3")
        continue
    else:
        break
if menu == 1:
    print("Lets go!")
elif menu == 2:
    print("Lets go!")
else:
    print("Quitting...")
```

The "if" where it says "if menu > 3 or menu < 1:" gives an error saying that:

"Unreachable codepylint(unreachable)"

Please help, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, the if statements will NOT execute as there is a continue before the if statement. The continue will return back to the while True statement

Comment: @JoeFerndz, I removed the "continue, and now on the line "if menu > 3 or menu < 1:", it says that the term "menu" is not defined. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem 1: continue statement**

To help you understand your code, i used a flowchart to draw the lines for you.

[image]

However, if you move the continue inside the except statement, then the code will pass onto the if statement on a successful try statement.

The challenge is, that the code is never going into the `if menu > 3....` statement, it always goes to `try` or `except` and then does the `continue`. So its looping itself skipping the `if menu > 3 ....` statement. That means, you never get out of the loop as it never gets to execute `break`.

**Problem 2: You said you removed the continue statement.**

When you remove continue from the statement, you create a new problem. If the code goes into except clause, variable menu did not get created properly. So when it goes to `if menu > 3 ...`, the variable has not been defined (due to except clause), and that gives you a new error.

**Solution:**

I would recommend to move the `continue` statement inside the `except` clause. That will take care of the problem. It will go back to while statement if there is an error with the input for menu. If it is successful, then your `if menu > 3 ...` will execute properly.

The modified correct code will be:

```
while True:
    try:
        menu = int(input("Make a selection: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Sorry, your input was not valid")
        continue #move this inside except
    
    if menu > 3 or menu < 1:
        print("Please use a number in the range 1-3")
        continue
    else:
        break
if menu == 1:
    print("Lets go!")
elif menu == 2:
    print("Lets go!")
else:
    print("Quitting...")
```

Comment: your diagram made it much easier to understand. I appreciate the help

Comment: @TahacemBakirhan If you think that this answered your question please mark it as correct (press the checkmark under the vote signs)